# Can I add 2 64 bit numbers in a 32 bit machine

Tags: memory, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, memory-address

I was asked this in an interview and my feeling at first was that each 64 bit number will be stored in two 32 bit memory locations and then the system can do normal addition arithmetic based on its Endian rules. But I did not get confirmation on whether my answer was right or not and i have been having doubts. I know this might be very basic but I need to know. Thanks

Comment: You didn't take into account that the numbers are represented in [`two's-complement notation`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: @alfasin: that's OK, I don't think it matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have the overflow bit, then you have to add the 31 lowest bits together first, and then you can check if the `2^31` place overflows*. Then you set that bit correctly. Then you add the highest 32 bits together, add 1 if it overflowed in *. Overflow on the highest 32 bits are OK, and handles the two's complement arithmetic nicely.

Answer (score 0):

My answer whould be:

Adding 2 numbers can result in at most 2 times the  aximu, number. So adding 2 32 bit numbers can at most result in an 33 bit number. Using the overflow flag of the cpu this bit 33 can be used. By adding the most significant 32bit first and than the least significant 32 bit and checking the overflow bit to add 1 to the most significant 32 bit part.

Does this answer your question?